# Must all code interacting with templated types also use templates?

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

Must all code interacting with templated classes also use templates?

Imagine

```
template<T>
class Data {
public:
    Data(T value) {
        this->value = value;
    };
    T getValue() {
        return value;
    };
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
private:
    T value;
};
```

There will be specific implementations of `size()` for several possible `T` (String, int, etc.).

Note: *I could have an abstract class, but then I wouldn't be able to have neither the constructor/getValue, nor virtual methods, because I would have to specify their argument/return value types.*

Further imagine that I have function such as

```
template<T>
size_t getSize(Data<T> value) {
    return value.size();
}
```

Although `size()` will be different for each different type, the sender (the `getSize()` method) shouldn't care about `T`.

So the question is **why is it necessary to template the function, and can I avoid it?**

Comment: You can avoid it if you only want to interact with a single specialisation of `Data`, but not if you want any `Data` in general.  Interacting with `Data<int>` doesn't require a template, for example, but interacting with `Data<T>` in general does, because each specialisation of `Data` is actually a different type.  Try adding `static_assert(std::is_same<Data<int>, Data<short>>::value, "Types are different.");` to your code, and you'll see it.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a [type erasure techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2872/type-erasure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Must all code interacting with templated classes also use templates?

Yes.  Note that what you have is a [class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) which is a way to express a family of classes.  It does not make a class.  You do that by instaniating the template with a type like `Data<int>` will stamp out a version of `Data` where `T` is an int.

> why is it necessary to template the function

The reason is that a `Data<int>` and a `Data<double` are not the same class.  Just like an `int` and `double` are different, you get different classes when instatiating the class template with different template parameter.  Beacuse of this if you want a function that can deal with anything the class template can produce then that function also needs to be f[unction template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) so it can stamp out a function for each different `Data` that is produced.

> and can I avoid it

One thing you could do is have `Data` dervive from a base class and then move `size` into the base class.  Then you could write the function to accept a reference to the base class instead of the class template.

Comment: So basically like an interface, right? I forgot that C++ has multiple inheritance and thus doesn't need to support interfaces. :) Thanks

Comment: @peter yeah, like an interface.  Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Data : public Base
{
public:
    Data(T value) {
        this->value = value;
    };
    T getValue() {
        return value;
    };
    size_t size()
    {
        return this->value.size();
    }
private:
    T value;
};

size_t getSize(Base& value)
{
    return value.size();
}

void test()
{
    std::vector<int> vi;
    Data<std::vector<int>> d(vi);
    getSize(d);
}
```